# Update the same field in all the childs

Tags: swift, firebase

I have the following structure in firebase database:

```
"profiles": {  
   "user_id" : {
      "id_profile_1" : {
          "photos" : ".."
          "selected" : "0"
       },
      "id_profile_2" : {
          "photos" : ".."
          "selected" : "0"
       }, 
      ...
   }
}
```

Is there any way to update simultaneously all the "selected" field in all the children at once?

I'm making this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let post = ["selected": "-1"]
ref.child("profiles").child("user_id").updateChildValues(post)
```

But it adds a new child at the "user_id" level.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

To clarify, the actual structure looks like this:

```
"profiles": {  
   "AZWul77p47.." : {
      "KeC9NCb4Kh..." : {
          "photos" : ".."
          "selected" : "1"
       },
      "Kj4yZOd6aJ..." : {
          "photos" : ".."
          "selected" : "0"
       }, 
      ...
   }
}
```

And when a user selects a different profile in the app the "selected" of this profile changes to "1" and all the others to "0". That's why I want to update all the others "selected" to "0" in one call.

Comment: No, Given your current data structure it is not possible. You can add another parent section called `selected` outside profiles node, in which you can give the sub-node header as 'Selected_1','Selected_2'..etc. Of Course whose efficiency will depend upon what exactly 'selected' means , and how many states will it have. ps : i went with this approach because you have taken `selected = -1` in above case, which is quite confusing in the conventional sense

Comment: @Dravidian thanks for the answer. I used -1 just as an example, the only valid values in the selected attribute are "0" or "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **No**.

You can either iterate over each *id_profile* and perform an `updateChild` call each time, or re-structure your database.

I suggest you consider the latter option if you frequently change *selected* value since iterating over all those children will be expensive.

**Update:**

If only 1 item can be selected at a time in a profile, then you can normalize (flatten) the structure. It would save you a lot of space relatively and make it easier to set the *selected*

```
"selectedItems": {
   "AZWul77p47.." : {                // profile id
      "selected": "KeC9NCb4Kh..."    // set it to the selected item id
   },
   ...
},
"profiles": {  
   "AZWul77p47.." : {
      "KeC9NCb4Kh..." : {
          "photos" : ".."
       },
      "Kj4yZOd6aJ..." : {
          "photos" : ".."
       }, 
      ...
   }
}
```

Whenever you a user selects a different item, just update the *selected* child with the newly selected item id

Comment: Thanks, yes I think I will move the "selected" to another place, or think a better structure.

Comment: I think I got what you're after from the update you made. Updated my answer! :-)

Comment: You are right, that is the best structure for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using multi-path updates if you know how many id_profile nodes you have. You can use a simple for loop - I am assuming you have 10 id_profiles below. Bear in mind (from Firebase docs),

> Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

```
var childUpdates = [String: Int]()
let numberProfiles = 10

for index in 1...numberProfiles {
    childUpdates["/profiles/user_id/id_profile_\(index)/selected"] = -1 
}
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I dont know the number of profiles, and the name of the profiles are random ids. I updated the answer.